# 'Copy to the clipboard' button works only on the first page of DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a data table in which there are columns and rows and one of them is a <kbd>copy</kbd> button which `onclick()` initiates a copy function and copies a particular row to the clipboard, it works normally on the first page but when I use the search or the pagination it does not work and the button does not initiate the javascript function.

I searched and found in StackOverflow that I need to reinitiate the data table, which I tried but it gives an error

> DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

i have used  the modified code that I tried after I searched StackOverflow after which it gives an error

> DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

```
('#datatable').dataTable({ "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
  //code
}});
});
```

```html
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" class="dass">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th>Reference</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Copy</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      $numm=1;
      $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM asd);
      $stmt->execute();
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      { ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo strtoupper($row['stid']); ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['ref']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['fname']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $row['lname']; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button onclick="textToClipboard<?php echo $numm;?>()">Copy</button>
          </td>
          <th>
            <script>
              function textToClipboard <?php echo $numm;?> () {
                var space = "       ";
                var x = document.getElementById('datatable').rows[<?php echo $numm;>].cells[1].innerHTML;
                 var y = document.getElementById('datatable').rows[<?php echo $numm;?>].cells[2].innerHTML;
                var z = document.getElementById('datatable').rows[<?php echo $numm;?>].cells[3].innerHTML;
                var text = x.concat(space, y, space, z, space, q, space, w);
                var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
                document.body.appendChild(dummy);
                dummy.value = text;
                dummy.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                document.body.removeChild(dummy);
              }
            </script>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <?php $numm++;
      } ?>
  </tbody>
```

How can I bind it with the data table?

Comment: if i bind it, it gives 
"DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3 "

Comment: Try to create single function outside of loop and call it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a good practice to redefine a function again and again in a loop like this - that is what's parameters are for. I can't test this code, but here's an approach i would recommend:

```
    <script>
      function textToClipboard(numm) {
        var space = "       ";
        var x = document.getElementById('datatable').rows[numm].cells[1].innerHTML;
        var y = document.getElementById('datatable').rows[numm].cells[2].innerHTML;
        var z = document.getElementById('datatable').rows[numm].cells[3].innerHTML;
        var text = x.concat(space,y,space, z,space, q,space, w);
        var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
        document.body.appendChild(dummy);
        dummy.value = text;
        dummy.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(dummy);
      }
    </script>

<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" 
           class="dass">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>No.</th>
                  <th>Student ID</th>
                  <th>Reference</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                  <th>Last Name</th>
                  <th>Copy</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php
              $numm=1;
           $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM asd");
           $stmt->execute();
           while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
           {

            ?>
            <tr><td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>

                  <td><?php echo strtoupper($row['stid']); ?> 
                   </td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['ref']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['fname']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['lname']; ?></td>
             <td><button onclick="textToClipboard(<?php echo $numm;?>)">>Copy</button></td>
                </tr>
           <?php
                $numm++;
          } ?></tbody>
```

So define one parametered function first, and then call that later.

Furthermore, I'm unsure on how datatables handles selecting `.rows[numm]` after you search or use the pagination function. Therefore an even safer solution would involve passing all your required parameters in the function call, something like this:

```
onClick="textToClipboard($row['ref'], $row['fname'], $row['lname'])"
```

But this relies entirely on what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: so which part should i change?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid Cannot reinitialise DataTable Warning, just add

```
"destroy": true,
```

while initialising it. That will reinitialise a datatable again when you call it second time.

Read more:

1. https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy
2. https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy() -- destroy method

Comment: i tried the destroy method but then the copy button does not work

Comment: can you show me what you have within this block ?
('#datatable').dataTable({ "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
  //code
}});
});

Comment: if all you want is to copy the data in table, DataTables already provide that functionality. 

You can read here about the copy method: https://datatables.net/reference/button/copy

Comment: I want to copy particular row and column